# yoga/Yoga.h header file not found after react-native(0.40.0) integration in the existing iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

After integrating react-native in my Swift iOS app, I am not being able to build. `yoga/Yoga.h file cannot be found.` I have gone through the docs, checked out the react-native github page, checked SO questions on a similar issue. None of the solutions seem to work.

Any help in this would be appreciated. This has ruined my day catastrophically!

Here's my pod file

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

 use_frameworks!


target 'MyCustomApp' do
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'


    pod 'React', :path => './node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTWebSocket',# needed for debugging
    'RCTText',
    'RCTImage'
    # Add any other subspecs you want to use in your project
    ]

end
```

Comment: Can you add more details of your problem ? Like any explicit error message or what you're trying to do exactly ? Your podfile content might be a good start.

Comment: @aimak edited my question

Comment: I am basically trying to get a successful build first. What I am trying to do is create a page in React-Native entirely for the native iOS App.

Comment: ok but what is Yoga.h ?

Comment: I'm battling the same problem. The build fails on this line https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React/Base/RCTConvert.h#L13 stating that `yoga/Yoga.h file cannot be found`

Comment: I have the exact same problem since I updated to 0.40, it was working fine before that

Comment: Ok for now I reverted to v0.30 & it is working. Let us hope they release a stable version soon.

Comment: Same issue since 0.4.0

Comment: logged issue here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11781

Comment: @aginsburg cool. The sooner they notice , the better it is.

Comment: The workaround posted by @wubadubalublub works with v0.39.2

Answer (score 4):

`Yoga` is `CSSLayout` renamed: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/7f8c2985a8e447fd18f8b9331d4f35abeadaeb0e.

It seems like this is an issue that has been going on in several `react-native` versions with `CSSLayout` and it just happens to have a different name now. Here is a workaround using `post_install`: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11272

Comment: I tried adapting the post_install solution to fix the Yoga.h not found error. See my Podfile here: https://gist.github.com/hbizira/dc3d92d8a144faaa333810bbed40de3e  Now I'm running into the following error: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qguxy2tnov3528j/Screenshot%202017-01-16%2015.25.15.png?dl=0

Comment: I've got the same issue. Any suggestions?