# React Native RTCAnimation not found

Tags: ios, git, react-native, cocoapods

I clone git and run in ios but `RTCAnimation` not found I use pods to code:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'
pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/Yoga.podspec'
pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [

'RCTAnimation',
]

target 'RNFirebaseStarter' do
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
end
```

and run in Terminal is shown

```
[!] The name of the given podspec `yoga` doesn't match the expected one `Yoga`

Unable to find a specification for `yoga (= 0.52.1.React)` depended upon by `React/Core`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try and follow [issue 463](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/463)?

> ### Solution
>
> instead of
>
> ```
> pod "Yoga", :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga"
> ```
>
> use lowercase yoga
>
> ```
> pod "yoga", :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga"
> ```

Or:

```
-pod 'Yoga', path: "./../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/Yoga.podspec"
+pod 'yoga', path: "./../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga.podspec"
```

(meaning the first line is replaced by the second one)

Note there might be side-effect as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41505616/6309) and [in this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11781#issuecomment-338431009)

> I've discovered that it appear in a project I'm working after change the disk to case sensitive.
>   CocoaPods seems name the Yoga project as  not
>
> Revert the disk fixed (at least locally) the issue.

See this [patch for example](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/7f8c2985a8e447fd18f8b9331d4f35abeadaeb0e).

Comment: Thank you. But after install in RTConvert,h not found Yoga.h

Comment: @salution That would be best addressed in a separate question: you cand escribe the new problem there.

Comment: @salution For instance, check first https://stackoverflow.com/q/41505616/6309 and https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11781